# Correlation function in the Langevin equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-differential-equations, statistical-mechanics

So the Langevin equation of Brownian motion is a stochastic differential equation defined as
$$m {d \textbf{v} \over{dt} } = - \lambda \textbf{v} + \eta(t)$$

where the noise function $\eta(t)$ has correlation function $\langle \eta_i(t) \eta_j(t') \rangle=2 \lambda k_B T \delta_{ij} \delta(t - t')$.

I have two questions. How does one actually calculate a correlation function and where exactly do the constants (with temperature, the Boltzmann constants etc) proceeding the delta functions originate here? I understand that the delta functions ensure that there is no correlation at different times etc, but I don't get where the rest comes from.

Thanks

Comment: These are physical constants. $\lambda$ is a friction coefficient. $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant, $T$ is the temperature of the fluid. Neglecting these constants, the process $\eta$ is a distribution valued Gaussian process called White Noise. It is related to the standard Wiener process by $W(t)=\int_0^t\eta(s)\,ds$. You can google all of this and/or find it in Wikipedia.

Comment: I know that they're physical constants, I was just wondering how they derive that expression for the correlation function. I couldn't find the derivation anywhere online

Comment: That's not a math question.